# Isolate containers on the jwilder/nginx-proxy network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm using [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) to host multiple (web)apps from a single server. This is working great except that all services can communicate with each other because they are all on the same network because that is required for the proxy to work.

Proxy `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"

services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ./data/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/share/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always

  letsencrypt-proxy:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: letsencrypt-proxy
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/share/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always



networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

App 1 `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"

services:

  app:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - ./application:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: app1.example.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: app1.example.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: user@example.com

  cache:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - cachedata:/data

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpasswd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
      MYSQL_USER: database_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: database_passwd
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  cachedata:
    driver: local
```

App 2 `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"

services:

  app:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - ./application:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: app2.example.com
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: app2.example.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: user@example.com

  cache:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - cachedata:/data

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpasswd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
      MYSQL_USER: database_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: database_passwd
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  cachedata:
    driver: local
```

With this setup both applications will use de `db` and `cache` instance of App 1. The only way to solve that is to give those services unique names like `app_1_db` and `app_2_db`. But then App 1 is still able to connect to the `app_2_db` which I would like to prevent.

Is there a way to isolate all services within their docker-composer.yaml file and still use the nginx proxy?

```
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can connect only the app(nginx) container from your apps to the `nginx-proxy` network. The only edit needed should be in the app's docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    networks:
      - default
      - nginx-proxy

networks:
  nginx-proxy:
    external: true
```

That way the `app` service will be connected to nginx-proxy and default networks at the same time. (If you omit networks key, service is always connected to the default network)

Resolving service names to containers ip's then works as expected as long as no container can see (across all networks it's connected to) two containers with same service name.

---

If you want even more isolation, you can create nginx-proxy network for every app. 
So in your nginx-proxy docker-compose you will have:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    networks: 
      - default
      - nginx-proxy_app1
      - nginx-proxy_app2

# letsencrypt-proxy service doesn't have to have networks key

networks:
  nginx-proxy_app1:
    external: true
  nginx-proxy_app2:
    external: true
```

and in your apps:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    networks:
      - default
      - nginx-proxy_app1

networks:
  nginx-proxy_app1:
    external: true
```

and

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    networks:
      - default
      - nginx-proxy_app2

networks:
  nginx-proxy_app2:
    external: true
```

That way in every "proxy" network there is only one (if you are not using docker-compose scaling) app container and the nginx-proxy container.

---

More reading:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
- https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#operations-for-standalone-containers-on-overlay-networks